# Unity Question: How to make all positions (with array) initialized?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm the beginner of game coding, and meet some problem...
I would like to make coin stack and then click the coin all the coin would become small and fly to dedicate position, however, the coin position wasn't initialized which causes the Vector3 of coin move up 0.1f every time...
Please help me to solve it!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;


public class createcoin : MonoBehaviour
{   public Transform RightCoinArea;
    public Transform LeftCoinArea;
    public Sprite sprite1;
    List<Vector3> rightcoinpos = new List<Vector3>();
    List<Vector3> leftcoinpos = new List<Vector3>();
    public Vector3 [] rightpos= new Vector3 [6] ; 
    public Vector3[] leftpos = new Vector3[6];
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rightcoinpos.Add(rightpos);
        leftcoinpos.Add(leftpos);
    }

    //create coin
    public async void coincreate()
    {
        //coin stack random
          for (float i = 0; i <= 0.1f; i += 0.1f)
            {
                var coin8 = await PoolSystem.Instance.GetGameObject(eBundle.Game, "Flycoin", 
                 rightcoinpos[Random.Range(0, rightcoinpos.Count)] += Vector3.up * i, new Vector3(0.4f, 0.4f, 04f), sFileExtension.Prefab, RightCoinArea);
            
            //to initialize sprite
            coin8.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite1;
                 
            }
                                              
       //coin stack random
        for (float i = 0; i < 0.2f; i += 0.1f)
            { 
var coin9 = await PoolSystem.Instance.GetGameObject(eBundle.Game, "Flycoin", leftcoinpos[Random.Range(0, leftcoinpos.Count)] += Vector3.up * i, new Vector3(0.4f, 0.4f, 04f), sFileExtension.Prefab, LeftCoinArea);

           //to initialize sprite

            coin9.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite1;
         }                
    }

   public void  Moveout()
    {
        //gameobject back to the objectpool

      if (RightCoinArea.gameObject.transform.localScale == new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
            {          
            PoolSystem.Instance.Recover(RightCoinArea.gameObject);
        }

     
        if (LeftCoinArea.gameObject.transform.localScale == new Vector3(0, 0, 0))

        {
           PoolSystem.Instance.Recover(LeftCoinArea.gameObject);

        }

        //delete all the position in List
        rightcoinpos.Clear();
        leftcoinpos.Clear();

        //to initialize the position
    
      Vector3 tempos_R =   rightpos; 
       Vector3 tempos_L =  leftpos;       

       rightcoinpos.Add(rightpos);
        leftcoinpos.Add(leftpos);

    }

public void click()
    {
        coin_test.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite2_test;
       //coin fly to end dedicate pos
        DOTween.To(setter: value =>
        {
         coin_test.position = Parabola(start_test.position, new Vector3(0, 4.5f, 0), 1.5f, value);
        }, startValue: 0, endValue: 1, duration: 1.5f)
            .SetEase(Ease.Linear);

        //change coin scale 
        transform.DOScale(0.0f, 2.0f).OnComplete(Moveout);
    }
     //Parabola
    public static Vector3 Parabola(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, float height, float t)
    {
        float Func(float x) => 0.5f * (-height * x * x + height * x);

        var mid = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, t);

        return new Vector3(mid.x, Func(t) + Mathf.Lerp(start.y, end.y, t), mid.z);
    }

}
```